# Difference between using ++ and +1 as argument

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers, operators, binary-tree

```
var levelOrder = function(root) {
const arr = [];

function traverse(node, level) {
    if (!node) return;

    if(arr[level] === undefined) {
        arr[level] = [];
        arr[level].push(node.val)
    } else {
        arr[level].push(node.val) 
    }
    
    
     traverse(node.left, level + 1);
     traverse(node.right, level + 1);
}

    traverse(root, 0);
    return arr;
};
```

In the recursion call to traverse function. Using

```
traverse(node.left, level + 1);
```

gives me the correct answer but

```
traverse(node.left, ++level);
```

gives me incorrect answer.

Let's say level is currently 0. My hypothesis is that the first example will  feed 1 as the second argument to the traverse function. Second example will assign 1 to level (`level = level + 1`) and feed level(which is 1) as the second argument to the traverse function.

Comment: `++` increments the variable (and evaluates to the pre or post-increment value, depending on which you use). Whenever it confuses you, best to separate them - increment one one line, and pass the variable on another line

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but you're forgetting that you recursively call `traverse()` twice. What happened in the second call with `level + 1`, and what happened with `++level`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume `level = 5;`

`level + 1` is an expression that returns the value `6` and doesn't change the value of `level` at all, so its value is still `5`.

`++level` is an expression that increments that value of `level` to `6` and then returns the value of `level` which is now `6`.

Twice in a row like in your function:

```
level + 1; // returns 6
level + 1; // returns 6
```

And now the other way:

```
++level; // returns 6
++level; // returns 7
```

That's why it's failing.